# dd-MM-yyyy date format with moment.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, momentjs

Would like to get date format like **12-September-2017** after adding months with `moment.js`. 
I'm using `datepicker` for date fields.

current output is **Th-10-yyyy**.

Also, getting warning

> moment.min.js:6 Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.

```
$(document).on("change", "#inputmonthadded", function (evt) {

    var input_value_inputstartdate = $('#inputstartdate').val();
    var input_value_inputmonthpurchased = $('#inputmonthpurchased').val();
    var input_value_inputmonthadded = $('#inputmonthadded').val();

    if (typeof input_value_inputstartdate != 'undefined' && input_value_inputstartdate) {

        var inputstartdate = moment(input_value_inputstartdate);

        var portalexpdate = inputstartdate.add(input_value_inputmonthadded, 'months');

        var formatedportalexpdate = portalexpdate.format('dd-MM-yyyy');

        $('#inputportalexpirydate').val(formatedportalexpdate);

    }
    else {

        $('#inputportalexpirydate').val('');
    }

});
```

Comment: Which is the value of `input_value_inputstartdate`?

Comment: value of input_value_inputstartdate = 12-September-2017

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use:

```
var formatedportalexpdate = portalexpdate.format('DD-MMMM-YYYY');
```

as stated in the [`format`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) docs.

Moment tokens are case sensitive, `dd` stands as day of the week, while `DD` stands for day of the month, use `MMMM` to get full month name and `YYYY`to get the 4 digit year.

Use [`moment(String, String)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) instead of `moment(input_value_inputstartdate)` to avoid *Deprecation warning* while parsing `input_value_inputstartdate`, in your case you can do something like:

```
var inputstartdate = moment(input_value_inputstartdate, 'DD-MMMM-YYYY');
```

The full code could be like the following:

```js
$(document).on("change", "#inputmonthadded", function (evt) {
  var input_value_inputstartdate = $('#inputstartdate').val();
  var input_value_inputmonthpurchased = $('#inputmonthpurchased').val();
  var input_value_inputmonthadded = $('#inputmonthadded').val();

  if (typeof input_value_inputstartdate != 'undefined' && input_value_inputstartdate) {
    var inputstartdate = moment(input_value_inputstartdate, 'DD-MMMM-YYYY');
    var portalexpdate = inputstartdate.add(input_value_inputmonthadded, 'months');
    var formatedportalexpdate = portalexpdate.format('DD-MMMM-YYYY');
    $('#inputportalexpirydate').val(formatedportalexpdate);
  }
  else {
     $('#inputportalexpirydate').val('');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" id="inputmonthadded">
<input type="text" id="inputstartdate" value="12-September-2017" readonly>
<input type="text" id="inputportalexpirydate" readonly>
<input type="text" id="inputmonthpurchased">
```

Comment: The snippet show no Deprecation Warning, are you using [`moment(String)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) elsewhere in your code? Please check it and replace string parsing with [`moment(String, String)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow moment's formatting style: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

Therefore: `format("D-MMMM-YYYY")`

Note: using `DD` will append zeroes e.g., 01, 02, 03, while `D` will use single value e.g., 1, 2, 3.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the input format as the second argument

```
var inputstartdate = moment(input_value_inputstartdate, "dd-MM-yyyy");
```

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/