# Live Clock Moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to display a live clock using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) , I did.

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
    $('#clock').html(moment().format('ddd M/d/y H:mm:ss'))
}, 1000);
```

## Today is 3/15

I kept getting the wrong date, and the time never refresh.

[image]

How do I make it work correctly ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dd-MM-yyyy date format with moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46185018/dd-mm-yyyy-date-format-with-moment-js)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `.setInterval()` to refresh the time after a second interval. Change the format correctly to show the date time correctly

```js
window.setInterval(function () {
    $('#clock').html(moment().format('ddd MM/DD/y H:mm:ss'))
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<p id="clock"></p>
```